# Is this a valid htaccess rule?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm learning a framework from a friend.. The second rule of the .htacces file is this

```
RewriteRule ^(app|cld)(/.*)?$ index.php [L]
```

But when i run this line in a regular expression checker it shows the / as invalid..
Can anyone explain me what the slash does in this example?

I understand that the `(app|cld)` means a request for the app or cld folder

Comment: Sounds like a delimiter issue for you. The RegEx is 100% valid and it's just checking for an optional path.

Comment: This rule matches urls like `domain.com/app`, `domain.com/app/`, `domain.com/app/XXX` (and the same for `cld`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid rule.

This regex:

```
^(app|cld)(/.*)?$
```

Means start anchor followed by app or cId followed by one of the:

1. end anchor `$`
2. `/` (slash) and end anchor
3. `/` (slash) and some text

So it matches any of the following:

1. `/app`
2. `/app/`
3. `/app/abc`
4. `/app/abc/def/`
5. `/cId`
6. `/cId/`
7. `/cId/abc`
8. `/cId/abc/def/`